# Warnings In TexStudio when compiling

Tags: beamer, titles, texstudio

Firstly, I'm working on a Beamer Presentation; it appears to work correctly but there are some problems.. for instance , it does not apear the title..Blocks etc..

I have some problems in relation with the messages of compilation, there are messages in red such as :

```
> ** WARNING ** Couldn't open font map file "kanjix.map". presentation_1.dvi -> presentation_1.pdf [1 ** WARNING ** Unparsed
> material at end of special ignored. Current input buffer is -->!
> /pgfH{/pgfheight exch def 0.75 setlinewidth [] 0...<-- ** WARNING **
> Unparsed material at end of special ignored. Current input buffer is
> -->! /pgfV{/pgfheight exch def 0.75 setlinewidth [] 0...<-- ** WARNING ** Unparsed material at end of special ignored. Current input buffer is -->! /pgfA{ /pgfdiff 8 index round cvi 8 index round ...<-- **
> WARNING ** Unparsed material at end of special ignored. Current input
> buffer is -->! /pgfR1{ newpath dup dup dup 0 360 arc clip newpa...<--
> ** WARNING ** Unparsed material at end of special ignored. Current input buffer is -->! /pgfR2{ newpath 0.5 add pgfcircx pgfcircy 3 2
> ro...<--
```

At the end is written down : The proccess ends normally.

But as I told before, when I compile and view the result the title does not apear, when I want to put blocks I can't, due to if I put blocks, the inside text does not appear and little problems like that.
What happen? Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  The errors relate to not finding some font related files including `kanjix.map`.  Questions: which engine are you compiling with? Is it `pdflatex`? Could you post a minimal amount of your source code? See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem changing the way to compile. Right now I'm compiling with `pdfLatex`. The "build and view" uses the following chain: `DVI->PS->PDF` chain.

But have some problems with a new presentation. I want to put images, but when compiling and view the presentation, the images are shown in black and white.

I have the package of `graphicx` in the preamble. But still is not working.

An example of how I code the way to put images is:

```
\centering{\includegraphics[scale=.45, natwidth=640, natheight=380]{g1.jpg}}
```

Any idea about how can I solve the problem?

Comment: You can go to Option and Configure to change the Build&View chain.